# Compling a c# application : an error : Identifier expected

Tags: c#

Can anyone please tell me why compiling a C# application with a .cs file containing the following piece of code is giving me an error . See below.

```
namespace defintions
{
    unsafe public struct name
    {
       char* firstname;
       char* lastname;
    } ;

   class Functions
    {
       [DllImport("C++Dll.dll")]
       public unsafe static extern long func(name *);    //error : Identifier expected

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function's parameter doesn't have a name (name * isn't a name).

Change it to

```
[DllImport("C++Dll.dll")]
       public unsafe static extern long func(name* theName);    //error : Identifier expected
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use unsafe code in your example. A class is always marshalled by reference to unmanaged code. Try this:

```
namespace defintions
{    
    public class name    
    {       
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        string firstname;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        string lastname;    
    } 


    class Functions    
    {       
        [DllImport("C++Dll.dll")]       
        public static extern long func(name theName);   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Very good point.  Always better to let the Marshal work with the unsafe code!